# Clicking on a tag when a date is set in the heading causes "no link found"

Tags: org-tags

I have a heading like so:

```
* First entry <2020-04-01>      :tag1:
```

Clicking on `:tag1:` doesn't work. I see the following error in the mini-buffer:

> user-error: No link found

Clicking on the date works as intended. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Do `C-h c` and then click on the tag: what binding does emacs report for that in the echo area? In my case, it says `<down-mouse-1> at that spot runs the command org-mouse-down-mouse`.

Comment: <down-mouse-1> (translated from <mouse-1>) at that spot runs the command mouse-drag-region

Comment: Having the `<2020-04-01> ` breaks the tag link, it seems. If I remove the date, the link works. Is that a bug or am I not allowed to have dates on the headline?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me: maybe report it to the Org mode mailing list?

Comment: Are you sure about the `mouse-drag-region`? Unless you double-clicked, it should be translated to <mouse-2> which runs the command `org-open-at-point` in both cases (with or without the date). But the context is different: it's `headline` without the date and `timestamp` with it: in the first case, `org-open-at-point` opens a tags view, in the second it raises the `No link found` error.

Comment: I can't get anything else. Actually, what happens is, the first time I click, I get nothing on the echo area for a moment. Then the text  `mouse-1-` appears as if it is waiting for something. So when I click again I get the message above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107147/discussion-between-nickd-and-aemacs).